# How is 2 considered a product of primes.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

I am working on a discrete math problem proving that all integers > 1 are a product of primes but I do not understand how 2, 3 , or 7 could be written as a product of primes considering they are prime? I want to assume it would be them * 1 but 1 is not prime. This is leaving me excruciatingly confused.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's a "product" with only one term

Comment: 2,3, and 7 are the product of one prime. Even 1 is the product of zero primes.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  You are correct that $1$ is not prime.  When the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) says that any number can be written as a product of primes, there could be any number of primes in the product.  For example, there could be a  thousand primes in the product, or there could be only one prime in the product, and the latter is the case when the number being factored is prime.